# How can I make the table take the available space along the height?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following table

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){

    final TheGroupPageArguments arguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
             Flexible(
              flex: 1,
              child: Align( 
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: DigitalSpeedMeter(),
              ),
            ),
             Flexible(
              flex: 6,
              child: Table(
                children: [
                  TableRow(children: [backButton(), backButton(), backButton()]),
                  TableRow(children: [backButton(), backButton(), backButton()]),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

But it only takes half the screen height. How can I make it strecht to it's parent's height?

[This is how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN2WH.png)

This is what it should look like

[This is what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP07Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Expanded" instead of "Flexible".

[image: Ex. of Expanded]

Comment: This is still not what I want tho. The buttons inside should be taking 100% over the cell space. And the table cells should be fractions of the height of the table.

Comment: I added an example of what it should look like to the question

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a good solution.
Anyone know a good way?

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  '0\nMPH',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 6,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          color: Colors.tealAccent,
                          child: Text("button1"),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          color: Colors.green,
                          child: Text("button2"),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            child: Text("button3"),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            color: Colors.amber,
                            child: Text("button4"),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image: sample]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following. A widget that makes the rows and columns dynamically based on the the widgets put into it.

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    
    class ExpandingGrid extends StatelessWidget {
    
      final List<Widget> tiles;
      final int columns;
    
      const ExpandingGrid({this.tiles, this.columns});
    
      int _rows(){
        return (tiles.length / columns).ceil();
      }
    
      int _tileIndex(int row, int column) => row * columns + column;
    
      Widget _gridTile(int row, int column){
        if(_tileIndex(row, column) < tiles.length)
        {
          return Expanded(
            child:  tiles[_tileIndex(row, column)],
          );
        }
        return Spacer();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
        return Column(
          children: 
          [
            for(int r = 0; r < _rows(); r++ )
              Expanded(
                child: Row
                (
                  children : 
                  [
                    for(int c = 0; c < columns; c++)
                      _gridTile(r, c),
                  ]
                ),
              )
          ]
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. How about this?

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Column(children: [
        Flexible(
          flex: 1,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  '0\nMPH',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Flexible(
          flex: 6,
          child: Table(
            children: [
              TableRow(children: [backButton(), backButton(), backButton()]),
              TableRow(children: [backButton(), backButton(), backButton()]),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    ),
  );
}

Widget backButton() {
  return Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 7 * 6 / 2 - 7,
    child: FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      color: Colors.tealAccent,
      child: Text("button"),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image: sample]